# Adding item to html list with JS when there is no ID

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a script to add some extra features to a menu. The current user-menu is a drop-down list with links such as My profile, My reports, etc. I'm looking to add another item, "My posts".

I'm having a couple of difficulties due to the way the site is working.

This is the code for the drop down:

```
<li class="user expandable">
    *list items*
</li>
```

I'm using `document.getElementById` to pick up elements but have no idea how to pick up the list and add an item to it. I believe there are other element pickers such as `class` but they didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Adding item to html list with JS when there is no ID

To get the first found item `document.querySelector` then use a css selector for example `document.querySelector('div')` to find the first div or `document.querySelector('.user')` to find the first element with class user

to get every item that matches `document.querySelectorAll` which will return an array of all the items matched.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.user.expandable');

function addMyNewRow(message, index = 0) {
  const node = document.createElement('li');
  node.innerHTML = message
  list.insertBefore(node, list.childNodes[index]);
}

function addChild() {
  addMyNewRow('clicked and added in first');
}

addMyNewRow("added in second", 2)
```

```html
<ul class="user expandable">
  <li>old list item</li>
  <li>old list item</li>
  <li>old list item</li>
  <li>old list item</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="addChild()">add list </button>
```

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly. Selects the menu right away. Cheers. Now to figure out the adding child ect on the list for the extra item :)

Comment: what are you wanting to be appended?

Comment: This is the list: https://i.imgur.com/c2kQsiU.png   I'm wanting to add an item there second down. At the mo im selecting the drop down and replacing it.all together. Tried insertbefore instead of using innertext but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: do you not have access to the html?

Comment: I do have the html of the list yes, could I perhaps copy the dropdown on page load. Then insert my bit of button into that before running the find element and replace with my content?

Comment: @NathanChaplin if you want to insert an element using javascript at a certain index you can use `insertBefore` but if you have the html and everything else is hardcoded id just put it there

Comment: Shall do html route. Seems more logical in my brain. Appreciate your responses, So many sites/people just replied with sarcy unhelpfulness. You sir deserve a medal. Ta very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something similar to what you're looking for:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $(".user").append("<li>Appended item</li>");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ol class="user expandable">
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
<button id="btn2">Append list item</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: he never said he was using jquery

Comment: Yes he can try it, is more easy to use Jqery

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "li" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( hfhfhfha ) );
  }
);
```

"this" keyword gives you the reference you need.

Comment: he never said he was using jquery